# Angularjs Init Service

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on AngularJs project which have top navigation items load from server using a service call

```
App.service('Menu', function($http){
   return {
       get:function(callback){
           $http.get('api/menu.json').success(function(menuData){
               callback(menuData);
           });
       }
   }
});
```

I'm using the same in my `BaseController` as mentioned below

```
App.controller('BaseCtrl', function($scope, Menu){
    $scope.menuData = {};
    Menu.get(function(menuData){
        $scope.menuData = menuData;
    });
});
```

My Menu looks blank for a while until the service call succeed and assign the value to the `$scope.menuData` is there any way to fetch the same before rendering the view.

Please let me know, I might have tried all possible ways to do this, but nothing worked :(

PS: I'm using AngularJS v1.2.9

Comment: have a look at `ng-cloak`

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand I have gone through the documentation of ng-cloak but didn't understand how it works and what part of my view I have to apply the same, can you please explain a bit. Thanks

Comment: `ng-cloak` basically doesn't display the binding expression in the view until the bindings have actually been set, I thought that was your problem initially, it's in a way a better approach than preventing the controller/view being rendered, because in a way the latter kills the point of SPAs having almost immediate route transitions and a very fluid nature.

Comment: I made a small edit to my answer, in the `Menu` service `getMenuPromise` should be pointing directly to the promise in the service, it shouldn't be a function returning a promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a promise from your service, and use that in your controller's resolve:

```
app.service('Menu', function($http) {
    var menuData = null;

    var promise = $http.get('api/menu.json').success(function (data) {
      menuData = data;
    });

  return{
          getMenuPromise: promise,
          getMenuData:function(){
            return menuData;
          }
   };
});
```

and in your route definitions:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/home',{controller:'BaseCtrl',
    templateUrl:'../homeTpl.html',
    resolve:{
      'menuData':function(Menu){
        return Menu.getMenuPromise;
     }
    }})
```

Now when `BaseCtrl` is instantiated the data is there:

```
app.controller('BaseCtrl', function($scope,Menu) {
  $scope.menuData = MyService.getMenuData();
});
```

Comment: The problem is my BaseCtrl is not assigned to any specific view, its a common controller for all views. Please suggest a way to resolve data in controller not in router. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best way to make sure data is available before rendering a view is to use the [`resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) property on your route.

If it returns a promise it will resolve that promise before actually rendering your view.

```
.when('/blah', {
   templateUrl: '/path/to/view.html',
   controller: 'myController',
   resolve: {
      menuItems: function($http){
         return $http.get('api/menu.json');
      }
   }
});
```

That value will be passed in to your controller as a dependency:

```
angular.controller('myController', function(menuItems){
   $scope.menuData = menuItems;
});
```

Comment: The problem is my BaseCtrl is not assigned to any specific view, its a common controller for all views. Please suggest a way to resolve data in controller not in router. Thanks

Comment: @AshokVishwakarma - You can't accomplish what you want that way. You can create a promise to resolve things inside your control and call `init()` or something like that, but you can't prevent the view from loading without using the route. The best you could do inside your controller is to create some sort of `ready` flag that gets flipped when everything is loaded and simply `ng-hide` or `ng-show` your content when it is ready.