# Calling a service for labels before the DOM initializes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dom, label

I am loading all the labels from a REST service and store in a angular Service and sharing across all pages and controllers.

But what I doubt is how this works if my Labels Service responds lately to the request.

Should it displays those expressions in the page?

```
servicesModule.factory('LabelService', function($resource){
    var Svc = $resource('/rest/labels', {}, {
        getAllLabels : {method:'GET'} 
    });
    var labels = Svc.getAllLabels();
    return {
        getLabels : function(){
            return labels;
        }
    }
});
```

What would be the best approach to load labels without any flickering or expression displays in my page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23200257/189756

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand, I am thinking to implement Josh answer in the post, is there a way to add resolve to all the routes at single place, instead of adding to individual routes .

Comment: Not that I know of, if you use nested routing with ui router though you can define a base state and all the child states will inherit that route's resolved data.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand: I followed your reply in other post and see a kind of delay between the page load and labels loading into them . . any idea?

Comment: It looks the loading the controller waits for the promise to resolve, but not the page. I want my page to be loaded after the promise got resolved during the app launching.